# Orthonormal basis in a built bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orthonormal, bilinear-form

Let $B = \{v_1, \cdots , v_n\}$ a basis of a vector space $V$ over a field $K=\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. We want to know if there exists a bilinear form $f : V × V \to K$ such that $B$ is an orthonormal basis of $V$ with $f$.

We want to build $f$ such that $f(v_i,v_i)=1$ and $f(v_i,v_j)\neq0$ if $i \neq j$. I feel like the statement is true but I don't have any idea of how to show it.

Comment: recall that any bilinear function can be defined by extension on a basis

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want $f(v_i,v_j)\neq 0$?

**Hint**: Consider an isomorphism $V\to \mathbf R^n$ or $\mathbf C^n$ mapping $B$ to the standard basis.

Comment: You just need to **declare** your basis orthonormal and extend by (bi)-linearity.

Comment: @GReyes: That is another way to do it. But it really is the same thing, really.

Comment: Sure. It is the same thing.